# How do I compute the file path for a user-written settings file in Java (JavaFX) that is compatible with Linux, Mac and Windows?

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, javafx

My JavaFX program needs to compute a file name path for various user-written files such as the product-specific preferences. For example, "Do you want to open your previous file the next time the program starts" and so on.  I have successfully experimented with https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX and "jpackage" for Windows at least, so it looks like I will shortly need a way to code, in a cross-platform manner, the "correct" path in which to store such files.

Is there a standard API or coding technique that will give me a file path that the program can write using user permissions that is "correct" for these native platforms?

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java/586345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a single piece of software which would do that but I think my answer to this questions [Java - Cross-platform filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680493/java-cross-platform-filepath/59680823#59680823) may be helpfull for you. It also mentions how the same can be achieved on Android for example.

Comment: OK, coding needed is well defined and the Java ecosystem has so far failed to provide an out-of-the-box solution for cross-platform software that I ought to use. If I open-source my library I'll be sure to provide this.